# converting RGB to HSV looses the boundary

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have following image
[image]

and I want to generate the mask for the area under green color. My code is following:

```
    img = cv2.imread(path + file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower = np.array([10, 180, 180])
    upper = np.array([130, 255, 255])
    thresh= cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower, upper)
    masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=thresh)
    #plt.imshow(masked)
    # get external contours
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

    # draw white filled contours on black background
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    for cntr in contours:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

    # invert so black regions on white background if desired
    mask = 255 - mask

    # show results
    #plt.imshow(img)
    plt.imshow( mask)
```

My output is [image]. The boundary is disconnected from the left and thats why the coountour is not filled. When I check the hsv_img, I get the following
[image]

So, something at rgb to hsv conversion causing the break in green boundary. Any idea how to fix it. All i care is generating the maskings

Comment: The image at the bottom is not derived from the one at the top, they’re different fish.

Comment: So the break in the boundary is not caused by the conversion to HSV, it was already there in the input.

Comment: Use morphology open to close your output. Then get the contour of that and draw it filled on a new blank image.

Comment: @fmw42. please answer it and i will accept it. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my correction to your code in Python/OpenCV.  Basically, you just need to add some morphology close to fill the gap in your line.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('fish_green_line.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# convert to hsv
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold
lower = np.array([10, 180, 180])
upper = np.array([130, 255, 255])
thresh= cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# draw white filled contours on black background
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
for cntr in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# invert so black regions on white background if desired
mask = 255 - mask

# save results
cv2.imwrite('fish_green_line_mask.png', mask)

# show results
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask Result:

[image]